# How to preserve emoji character in a S3 file with node.js

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am uploading a JSON string from my nodejs server, into S3, via the [`s3.upload`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) method.

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.upload({
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key:  'myPath/' + thing.id + '.json',
    Body: JSON.stringify(thing),
    ContentType: 'application/json'
})
```

If in the above snippet, the `thing` object has a String property containing emojis, how would I modify this operation in order to preserve the emoji characters.

At my node server, I can see that the emoji is being stored in the DB and served correctly. It is only after upload do the characters lose their integrity. I think there's some character encoding trick that I can apply to the JSON.stringify result, but I don't yet know the details. Asking for help here.

JSON I get at node server:

[image]

JSON I see at S3:

[image]

Comment: What does "Example JSON at S3:" mean? It looks like the same string, just interpreted incorrectly. So, what does interpret it on the second screenshot.

Comment: The example shows what I am seeing at my nodejs server and at S3, via the browser.

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Have you tried to retrieve data from S3 and compare bytes? At the moment it's not clear what you have done to confirm the problem even exists.

Comment: I want the string in S3 to match the string at node server. How is this not clear?

Comment: Well, I think it matches. They look the same. In the second case you did not specify the right encoding though. And that's what I asked - how did you confirm the problem even exists.

Comment: Focus on the emojis:    

Comment: I have. How did you output both things (I'm surprised I need to ask this for the 4th time).

Comment: Well, I'm sure bytes are identical, but in the second time they are not encoded properly. You have provided 2 screenshots and 0 lines of code on how you retrieved the data. My point here is: the data is fine, it's how you output it is broken.

Comment: " I think there's some character encoding trick that I can apply to the JSON.stringify result, but I don't yet know the details. Asking for help here. "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153181/discussion-between-zerkms-and-julian-soro).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As zerkms stated, the bytes in the file coming from S3 were the same as the node server's file. The issue was that S3's web client did not tell the browser to use uft-8 when opening the JSON file from S3. As a result, Chrome showed the bytes in the way the screenshot displays.

This is all true and good, however, it doesn't help solve the original desired result, which is to see the emojis from the S3 web client.

**The fix was to add `charset=utf-8` to the s3.upload options, like so:**

```
s3.upload({
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key:  'myPath/' + thing.id + '.json',
    Body: JSON.stringify(thing),
    ContentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
})
```

Additionally, it is worth nothing that setting `ContentEncoding: 'utf-8'` did not result in the desired behavior.

Comment: `utf-8` is a *character* encoding, not a *content* encoding.  *"The `Content-Encoding` header field indicates what content codings
   have been applied to the representation, beyond those inherent in the
   media type... content coding values indicate an encoding transformation... applied to a representation.  Content codings are
   primarily used to allow a representation to be compressed or... transformed without losing the identity of its
   underlying media type and without loss of information."* - [RFC-7232](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.2.1). Most commonly, `gzip`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real problem in this very case: the data is uploaded correctly, it is just S3 does not serve the encoding (it simply does not know it) and google chrome does not have enough context to guess it right.

Answer (score 1):

**Incase anyone needs to do this via the AWS cli:**

`aws s3 sync ./build s3://your-s3-bucket --exclude "*.js"`

*uploads all build folder files regularly, except js which contains utf-8 emoji characters*

then

`aws s3 sync --content-type "text/html; charset=utf-8" ./build s3://your-s3-bucket --exclude "*" --include "*.js"`

*uploads js files that contain utf-8 emoji characters with utf-8 encoding*

*note: option order is very important in aws-cli